# Can't install Tweaks on 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-hera

I added the correct repository ok but when I try to install Elementary Tweaks i get this message in terminal

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I haven't seen any instructions anywhere saying anything about needing to be root to install it so what's the problem? I'm relatively new to Linux and keen to learn and progress but issues like this are putting me off.

Answer (score 2):

You always need root when you install any deb file or using `apt` to install anything. Make sure to use `sudo` on such commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command elevated using `sudo`

```
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS. Your participation is much appreciated. Please let me inform you that community loves detailed answers. Try to explain why you are instructing to use this command. Have a nice day!